# Download File through headers from different server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have PDF file placed on different (FILE-Server) server machine, and the IIS machine on which my MVC application is hosted have rights to that File-Server. From IIS machine i can access the file through following URI:

```
file://file-server/data-folder/pdf/19450205.pdf
```

I want to enable my MVC app's users to download their respective files by clicking on download link or button. So probably i would have to write some Action for that link/button.

I tried to use File return type for my Action method in following way:

```
public ActionResult FileDownload()
{
    string filePth = @"file://file-server/data-folder/pdf/19450205.pdf";
    return File(filePth , "application/pdf");
}
```

but the above code gives exception of URI not supported.

I also tried to use FileStream to read bytes inside array return that bytes towards download, but FileStream also gives error of not proper "Virtual Path" as the file is not placed inside virtual path, its on separate server.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult Download()
{
    var document = = @"file://file-server/data-folder/pdf/19450205.pdf";
    var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
    {
        // for example foo.bak
        FileName = document.FileName, 

        // always prompt the user for downloading, set to true if you want 
        // the browser to try to show the file inline
        Inline = false, 
    };
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
    return File(document.Data, document.ContentType);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies, but both suggestion did not work.

as file needs to be accessed over URI, using FileInfo gives error:  URI formats are not supported.

I managed to get this done through following mechanism:

```
    public ActionResult FaxFileDownload()
    {
        string filePth = @"file://file-server/data-folder/pdf/19450205.pdf";

        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        Stream s =  wc.OpenRead(filePth);

        return File(s, "application/pdf");

    }
```

Thanks to All.